# Calling addEventListener after setState seems to run event twice

Tags: reactjs

If I add an event listener after calling `setState`, I would expect that event listener to only get called if I trigger that event again.  However, from the example below, when I click on the div, the event listener is called after the state is changed.

It doesn't happen if I remove the `addEventListener` or if I call `evt.stopPropagation()` inside `toggleOpen`, but I'm wondering why the event listener is getting called if I'm setting it after thte state is changed.

Doesn't `setState` change the state asynchronously, implying that the callback would be called after the event propagates?

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import css from './Dropdown.scss';


export class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  toggleOpen = (evt) => {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.toggleOpen);

    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
    }, () => {
      window.addEventListener('click', this.toggleOpen);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const dropdownContentClasses = classNames(css.dropdownContent, {
      [css.dropdownContent_open]: this.state.open,
    });

    console.log(this.state.open)

    return (
      <div className={css.dropdownContainer}>
        <div onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
          {this.props.title}
        </div>
        <div className={dropdownContentClasses}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird!

Adding event listener on `document` instead of `window` fixes the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/y09h3nuf/

Answer (score 2):

2 things. First, from https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate you want to use the `prevState` property to calculate your new state:

```
toggleOpen = evt => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return { open : ! prevState.open };
  });
}
```

Second, it's better to add your event handler during the `componentDidMount()` phase, and remove it during `componentWillUnmount()` phase:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('click', this.toggleOpen);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('click', this.toggleOpen);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that answers my question though.  Changing setState to use `prevState` doesn't fix the issue.  Moving the listener to `componentWillMount` makes it so that the Dropdown opens on any click on the window.  My question is around why the event listener is getting called on the same click that sets the state, even though the event listener gets added after the state updates and the event propagates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like by the time the propagation reaches the window, the listener is added and then calls the eventListener. Adding event.stopPropagation should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the window event on toggleOpen, i would suggest to add the event inside `componentDidMount` with a `state.open` check.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.state.open && this.toggleOpen(e);
    });
}
```

I added a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87489/